# Unknown location of WordPress themes in React

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I downloaded and was running [this React project](https://github.com/imranhsayed/react-with-wordpress/tree/jwt-verify-with-node/src). It compiled successfully and it works for me.
But see the following:

```js
<div className="jumbotron">
    <h4>Login</h4>
    { error && <div className="alert alert-danger" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ this.createMarkup( error ) }/> }
    <form onSubmit={ this.onFormSubmit }>
        <label className="form-group">
            Username:
            <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="username"
                value={ username }
                onChange={ this.handleOnChange }
            />
        </label>
        <br/>
        <label className="form-group">
            Password:
            <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                name="password"
                value={ password }
                onChange={ this.handleOnChange }
            />
        </label>
        <br/>
        <button className="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit">Login</button>
        <p>{ loading && <img src={Loader} className="loader" alt="Loader"/> }</p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Where are `btn-primary`, `alert-danger`, etc. defined?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes `btn-primary` and `alert-danger` are part of bootstrap, a framework for developing websites. You can find the docs for the buttons [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/); for the alerts [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/).

The bootstrap css file is loaded in the `index.pug` file.

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

Note that this has absolutely nothing to do with wordpress. Bootstrap is a completely independent framework and can, as such, be incorporated in any website whatsoever, wordpress or not.